# Call $().dropdown inside react component

Tags: jquery, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using react version of **Semantic-UI** in a project and i need to create a custom dropdown component which has slightly **different inner html structure** than semantic-ui dropdown. So i decided to define a new class to return my desired html structure like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Icon} from 'semantic-ui-react';

class CustomDropdown extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(!!window.jQuery); // outputs 'true', which means jquery is defined 
        $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
                <input name="states" type="hidden"/>
                <span className="highlight"></span>
                <span className="bar"></span>
                <label>Some text</label>
                <Icon name="dropdown"/>
                <div className="default text">States</div>
                <div className="menu">
                    <div className="item" data-value="AL">Alabama</div>
                    <div className="item" data-value="AK">Alaska</div>
                    <div className="item" data-value="AZ">Arizona</div>
                    <div className="item" data-value="AR">Arkansas</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CustomDropdown;
```

Jquery is loaded using webpack `ProvidePlugin`:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
}),
```

but when i use this component in my codes, the line `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown()` gives error :

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function`

So how can i use `.dropdown()` function inside my react component?

Comment: have you tried jQuery('.ui.dropdown').dropdown() ?

Comment: @beaumontwebdev same error : `jQuery(...).dropdown is not a function`

Comment: Are you also loading the `dropdown` plugin somehow? It's not a regular jQuery method. You could try logging `!!window.jQuery.fn.dropdown` to see if it's available for you.

Comment: @m90 that's what i need to know, how to import `dropdown` js plugin ? tried `!!window.jQuery.fn.dropdown` and it returns false

Comment: @MehranTorki to be on the same page the `dropdown` function is provided by `semantic-ui-react` since from what I know `jquery`  does not provides such kind of function

Comment: the `dropdown` function belongs to which package ? because it does not belongs to `semantic-ui-react` since I scanned your code again and `dropdown` function was not coming from `semantic-ui-react`

Comment: @Gardezi When i include directly [jquery.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js) and [semantic.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.12/semantic.js) in my template as script tags, then .dropdown() works fine in browser console.

Comment: @MehranTorki is `semantic-ui-react` `semantic.js` ???

Answer (score 0):

@MehranTorki you will need to import dropdown function semantic.

and you will need to do something like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

// TODO: This is missing functionality for sub-menu here from SUI core examples.
// The "Publish To Web" item should contain a sub-menu.

const DropdownExampleDropdown = () => (
  <Dropdown text='File'>
    <Dropdown.Menu> // -------------------------------
      <Dropdown.Item text='New' />
      <Dropdown.Item text='Open...' description='ctrl + o' />
      <Dropdown.Item text='Save as...' description='ctrl + s' />
      <Dropdown.Item text='Rename' description='ctrl + r' />
      <Dropdown.Item text='Make a copy' />
      <Dropdown.Item icon='folder' text='Move to folder' />
      <Dropdown.Item icon='trash' text='Move to trash' />
      <Dropdown.Divider />
      <Dropdown.Item text='Download As...' />
      <Dropdown.Item text='Publish To Web' />
      <Dropdown.Item text='E-mail Collaborators' />
    </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>
)
```

to see what this code shows look at this url

https://react.semantic-ui.com/maximize/dropdown-example-dropdown

Please look at the code samples over here for more examples

https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown#dropdown-example-dropdown

I have copied the whole example but you just need to use the code which has the commented //------ line. And import like the DropDown like I have imported to get things working

Comment: @If you still need any help feel free to ask

Comment: honestly i still don't know how to implement a html structure like `<span className="highlight"></span><span className="bar"></span>` using dropdown item or menu. A little bit more clarification will save me lots of time. thanks

Comment: Well sir if you are going to go with the answer that I posted above then I don't think you need to provide your own html. Just give it your classes and labels etc and the rest of the is left for the component 

but if you still want to go with your own html then try to load sematic.js like you loaded jquery and do what you are doing right now and see if it works

Comment: if you till need help feel free to ping me